# java - is it possible accede and set to a static variable of another class

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-variables

I would like to accede and set a static variable from another class using a method static of this other class.

This is the example code:

```
public class A {


    private static HashMap<Integer, String> hmFromIdToDesc = null;


    public static void setHm(HashMap<Integer, String> hm) {
    if(hmFromIdToDesc == null) DummyContent.hmFromIdToDesc = hm;}
}
```

The other class where i call static method:

```
public class B{

    private HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    A.setHm(hm);
}
```

I think that in this code there is something deeply wrong, but i have to modify a code and the class A is used only in a static way and so i would like to maintain this kind of usage.

Compilator say that on A.setHm(hm) i have a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

I would like to know if there is a way to set a static variable from a static method in other class.

Thank you for your answers!!!

EDIT:

```
public class B{

    private HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    void myMethod(){
        A.setHm(hm);
    }
}
```

The really situation is that, i try, like you say @Vladimir, to use static{}(i mean the block) but is impossible inside the method and use static{} outside of myMethod is a problem beacuse i must put many variables static but in my code is very difficult to do that(the code posted is only an example to better understand my problem).

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you do `hm` non static? If you want to static initialize objects, `hm` must be `static` and `A.setHm(hm)` must be called from `static` block.

```
public class B {
    private static HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    static {
        A.setHm(hm);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question, thank you for your answer in the meanwhile.

Comment: I've understand that with static i must use all variables and methods static, but i think that was becoming a mix of that, and i risk to lose my mind. So i've decided to eliminate most static that i can. Really thank you for your help.